# How do you get a handle to view controllers in a storyboard for transitioning within a container controller

Tags: ios

My issue is I want to call transitionFromViewController:toViewController::: to change view controllers in a container view. But if the first controller is not created programatically but instead is created by the storyboard then how can I get a handle to it in order to pass it to transitionFromViewController?

More details:

I want to create a container controller that contains either controller A or controller B at app launch depending upon a  flag read from defaults.

In my storyboard I have placed a container view within the initial controller and when doing so IB automatically created a linked VC scene, which I have set as View Controller A.

I have also created a scene for view controller B (however am unable to link it to the initial view controller as doing so disconnects view controller A. So I presume IB only permits one VC to be connected to a container view).

In the initial controller's viewDidLoad I am planning to place a call to transitionToViewController to switch from controller A to controller B depending upon the state flag.
The problem is how do I get a handle to controller A? I am not creating controller A in code, IB is creating it automatically - so I tried adding a property for it in the initial controller but IB does not permit me to drag and drop a link using the IB assistant between controller A and the property. So how else can I get a handle to it in order to pass it to transitionToViewController:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using container view on storyboard for embed child controller then you can get the child controller by below code in viewDidLoad

`AController = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];`

if there is more then one child view controller then you can iterate self.childViewControllers to find each one.

And you can instantiate B Controller to call transitionFromViewController

`[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BController"];`

And then you call something like this
    .
    .
    .

```
[AController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self addChildViewController:BController];

[self transitionFromViewController:AController
                  toViewController:BController
                          duration:0.0f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                        animations:^{
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [BController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            [AController removeFromParentViewController];
                        }];
```